# How to make your eps image from \includegraphics be inside some border and have some description in it?

Tags: graphics

So we do  `\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{myfig.eps}` to get image on the page. But how to wrap it into border and make itassignable with some automated image number like `image N` label like `image about...`

\myincludegraphics[scale=0.75]{myfig.eps}{Description}

So point is - How to get something like this:
[image]?

Comment: A LaTeX tutorial or a book like [`lshort`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lshort) might help you get better answers to this and maybe also some of your future questions.

Comment: it seems like what you're describing is a *figure* with a *caption*.  You might find the `figure` environment and `\caption` command useful.

Comment: What is a groder anyway?

Comment: @Matthew: Might be a typo. In the text he says "into a border". The urban dictionary lists 'groder' but it doesn't make sense here.

Comment: @Martin: Don't think I didn't check the Urban Dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very basic question covered in every LaTeX beginner's guide. I recommend you to read such a guide if you haven't done it yet.

Use a figure environment

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{picture-file-name}
\caption{Some description of the picture}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: The guide a read told me not to use the optional argument of `figure` by default :-) which IMHO is a bad habit from users migrating from Word. At least it was in my case ;-)

Comment: @Martin: But the automatic placing isn't very good too. I prefer to leave out placement specifiers while developing a document, and then, after the text is written, fine-tune the positions where needed. But I agree `!htb` is rather aggressive — one should try `t`, `b` or `p` first.

Comment: @Andrey: The default specifier is stored in `\fps@figure` (and `\fps@table`) and can be changed globally by redefining this macro, which removes the need to always use the optional argument.

Comment: 1) does `\includegraphics` requirew any special  `\usepackage`  because apparantly my TeXworks app compiles it all but does not output an image into pdf=(

Comment: @Kabumbus: It needs the `graphicx` package. But note that `pdflatex` doesn't support EPS images. It needs to be converted with e.g. `epstopdf` first. Some modern versions of `pdflatex` do this automatically if the `-shell-escape` option is enabled.

Comment: Ok I admit I should have given the example without optional placements. However I will leave it like this now so that others can read and understand your comments. I agree that usually I (too) don't specify anything and only in cases where it is necessary I add the occasional [!ht] or so. In scientific documents with a larger number of figures too much floating can become a bit annoying. \includegraphics needs the \usepackage{graphicx} package

Comment: What about the groder? Maybe the material in section 27 of [epslatex.pdf](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/epslatex/english/epslatex.pdf) would help with this.